# .htaccess redirect shows multiple %20 when URL contains space on HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, https, spaces

I have some old URLs that I need redirected, unfortunatelly some of them contain spaces. I redirect them to my `redirect.php` script, but for some reason when the URL contains space or `%20`, in the URL after redirection this %20 repeats unlimited times. This seems to only happen now when we switched the server to HTTPS, when running on http subdomain or on my local it works correctly.

My rule is:

`RewriteRule ^/?(gallery\.php)(.*) /redirect.php$2 [R,L]`

This works correctly:

`gallery.php?place=name` --> `redirect.php?place=name`

But this happens when url contains space:

`gallery.php?place=long%20name` -->

`redirect.php?place=long%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name`

I tried adding `[B]` and `[NE]` flags but no success. Is there anything I am missing?

**UPDATE 1:**
To exclude other rules in htaccess, I have created a new example. I have empty directory `/test/` , inside is empty file `/test/index.php` and `/test/.htaccess` file, which contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)(.*) /$2 [NE,R,L]
```

That is all. Still the behaviour is weird, eg:
/test/index.php?a=xy works as expected, but /test/index.php?a=x%20y repeats the %20 sign.

Comment: Interesting, it should work. It works for me with your exact code, using SSL. Do you have other rewrites/redirects in your .htaccess? If so posting the whole thing in your question might shed some light.

Comment: @Vrac I have updated my question and added live example

Comment: Do you control this server? Set `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` in httpd.conf and tail the apache error log.

Comment: @Vrac , thanks unfortunately I don't, it's grid server on Media Temple. I checked the error logs and only suspicious lines contains the following: `[Thu Jul 21 19:16:24 2016] [error] [client 120.22.83.227] ModSecurity: Rule 7fcaac4886c8 [id "-"][file "/etc/apache2/mod_security/custom/jetpack.conf"][line "66"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "mattlauder.com.au"] [uri "/old-content-redirect/gallery.php"] [unique_id "V5GB@EANwBYAADnBITUAAAB5"]`

Comment: Your host is using custom mod_security rules, it is possible they have some kind of filter for spaces that is going haywire. It's tough to say what could be wrong with the configuration but clearly there is a config issue, your code is quite simple and should work (and does in the multiple servers I tried it on). Perhaps it's time to take the issue to your host.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I managed to go around the problem by reordering the .htaccess rules. So I do all redirects from HTTP to my redirect script which is on HTTP as well. This script then resolves the correct new URL, that is already on SSL without spaces, and then the script redirects there. Fortunatelly all old URLs are on HTTP so it is sufficient, I don't need this parameter redirects to happen on SSL.

Also the `[NE]` flag is helpful when redirecting URLs with `%20`, as it prevents the percentage sign to be further encoded in new URL.